# SSL_read() returns SSL_ERROR_SSL error code with "Resource temporarily unavailable" system error

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, openssl, client-server

### I have created Linux Client-Server application using TCP socket.

- I have used **OpenSSL library** to validate certificates and keys before connection establishment
- Here, Server App using OpenSSL **1.1.0** version, Whereas Client App using OpenSSL **3.0.8** version.
- Both Server and Client app able to connect to each other at startup.

---

- **Case** : When user perform some action at Server Side in result **server restart itself** which is expected behavior, hence for few seconds **SSL connection get broken** between Client and Server
- So Client again try to connect to Server. Client sends connection handshaking packets and server respond with reply packets and client again connected to server
- But in next read, SSL_read() returns -1 at Client side and failed

  ```
    /* --> SSL_read() returns -1 */
    int read_ret = SSL_read(sslObj, buffer, size); 
    if (read_ret <= SSL_ERROR_NONE)
    {
            /* --> SSL_get_error() returns 1 means SSL_ERROR_SSL*/
            int read_error = SSL_get_error(sslObj, read_ret);

            /* --> strerror_r() returns "Resource temporarily unavailable" with errno : 11 */
            strerror_r(errno , systemError, bufferSize);
    }
  ```

Here , As shown in above code
After connection established ,and client try next read from socket using SSL_read() , it failed with ssl err **SSL_ERROR_SSL** and system error **Resource temporarily unavailable**

This behavior kept on reapeat

1. Again client try to connect to server
2. Connection get established between Server and Client
3. Again Client try to read next data via SSL_read() and it failed
4. Again Step 1 happens and this goes on

**My Questions**

1. As I am using **different OpenSSL version** at Server and Client side , Is it causing this behavior ?
   [I believe OpenSSL versions are backward compatible]
2. As per OpenSSL site, **SSL_ERROR_SSL** means

> A non-recoverable, fatal error in the SSL library occurred, usually a
> protocol error. The OpenSSL error queue contains more information on
> the error. If this error occurs then no further I/O operations should
> be performed on the connection and SSL_shutdown() must not be called.

So Is this OpenSSL library error ? If so then how to handle our case ?

3. In which cases **Resource temporarily unavailable** syserr with errno: 11 occurs ?

Please help. Thanks

Comment: "Resource temporarily unavailable" means `errno` reported `EAGAIN`, which is a non-fatal error reported by non-blocking sockets. I think `SSL_get_error()` *should* have reported one of the `SSL_ERROR_WANT_...` errors instead of `SSL_ERROR_SSL`. But as OpenSSL's documentation (which you quoted) says, for `SSL_ERROR_SSL` you should be checking OpenSSL's own [error queue](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/ERR_get_error.html) for details about why it failed.

Comment: Hi @RemyLebeau ,  I tried to get more details from SSL error queue                          Client:  SSL Read error =>                                                                              | SSL_read_ret : 0 |                                                                                            
SSL_ERROR :1 means SSL_ERROR_SSL |                        
SSL_ERROR_str : error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading- |
SSL_ERROR_desc : error:00000005:lib(0)::reason(5) |
 ErrMsg[0]:No error information |

Comment: "unexpected eof while reading" means the peer closed the TCP connection on their end without first sending a close notify over the TLS connection. You should not have gotten an `EGAIN` for that, which makes me think `errno` was still holding an error code from an earlier operation (all the more reason why `errno` doesn't make a lot of sense to look at for `SSL_ERROR_SSL` only for `SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL`)

Comment: Per the `SSL_get_error()` documentation: "*The `SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL` with `errno` value of 0 indicates unexpected EOF from the peer. **This will be properly reported as `SSL_ERROR_SSL` with reason code `SSL_R_UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING`** in the OpenSSL 3.0 release because it is truly a TLS protocol error to terminate the connection without a SSL_shutdown().*"

Comment: Agreed , Now after reading several blogs , used ERR_clear_error() before every SSL IO operation which followed by SSL_get_error.

Comment: Here,  ERR_clear_error() shall clear SSL error queue for target thread . So now before calling SSL_read() and SSL_write() , I have called  ERR_clear_error() at client side code

Comment: @RemyLebeau , Please refer above comments to help

Comment: help with what? Seems you already figured out what to do

Comment: Actually There are two case (1) when some action done at server -> hence connection broken for few seconds ,                                                                                             
 Here we get logs [SSL_ERROR_NO:1, SSL_ERROR_STRING:error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading
, SYSTEM_ERROR_STRING[0]:No error information.]                                                             For this case , now server and client get connected after few seconds

Comment: For seconds case : no action at server or client -> still connection get broken and restored -> this happened in every half n hr ..............Here we get logs [SSL_ERROR_NO:5, 
  SSL_ERROR_STRING:,     SYSTEM_ERROR_STRING[11]:Resource temporarily unavailable.]    Here note that this time SSL_ERROR is 5 means SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL with no SSL_ERROR_STRING is empty........ errno is 11 means Resource temporarily unavailable......I  can't figure out why this is happening

Comment: @RemyLebeau , I need your guidance on case 2 where I got SYS_ERROR_SYSCALL with [Resource temporarily unavailable] system error , What could be reason for this error